# Veracrypt 1.24 cannot be used anymore for mounting volumes as normal user

Tags: debian, mount, sudo, veracrypt

I recently upgraded my Veracrypt under Debian Linux 10 (to newest version 1.24 hotfix 1, from 1.23).

Previously, I was able to mount the volumes as normal user. To achieve this, I followed these steps: [Mount volumes as a normal user](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt#Mount_volumes_as_a_normal_user)

The 1.23 version worked fine with those setting. But after the upgrade, the Veracrypt keeps asking for the "administrative privileges". I checked: the sudoers list and the groups settings are correct.

The veracrypt 1.24 prompts following window when trying to mount:
[image: Screenshot from application]

What is the reason of this? Why I can't mount volumes anymore as normal user?

Comment: `groups` says `truecrypt`? `which truecrypt` says `/usr/bin/truecrypt`? what if you use `sudo truecrypt ...`?

Comment: oh, in that case, did you change truecrypt to veracrypt in the manual you linked. if the binary name changes you have to change the sudoers to allow bin/veracrypt instead of bin/truecypt. you can rename the group too I guess (doesn't matter but may be confusing if truecrypt group uses veracrypt binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sudoers entry only works if the program is called with sudo. Probably Veracrypt previously called itself with sudo and don't do so since Hotfix 1.24.

To solve your problem, you can add the "sudo" to the exec line in the **/usr/share/applications/veracrypt.desktop**

```
Exec=sudo veracrypt %f
```

Comment: I have a problem with this:

If I start the application with "sudo veracrypt", then the app will be run as root.

If I start(ed) without "sudo", then it ran as user. And this was no problem perviously.

Comment: The Verycrypt GUI was not run as root in the past, but the mount command has always been (as that's the only way a sudoers entry works).

I'm not sure why this is a problem for you, but this is currently the only way to continue using the Veracrypt-GUI as a regular user.

As an alternative, you could use an own starter or script to mount your containers.
`sudo veracrypt [OPTIONS] VOLUME_PATH [MOUNT_DIRECTORY]`

Comment: This issue is already known and may get fixed in future https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/b738c75977/?limit=25&page=2